# IPython Notebook Multiple Checkpoints

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I see that IPython Notebook has a menu item: `File > Revert to Checkpoint`, but this never contains more than a single entry for any of my notebooks.

Is there a way to allow this menu to hold multiple checkpoints? I can't find documentation about how to do this anywhere on the web.
Thanks.

Also, I put in the green box as a highlight.

[image: image showing only a single entry to 'Revert to Checkpoint' list.]

Comment: What happened to this option?? I don't see it in 2.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Bookstore](https://github.com/rgbkrk/bookstore) ([post on rackspace](http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/bookstore-for-ipython-notebooks.html)) is the only storage backend that supports multiple checkpoints for now. We hope that someone will write a git backend at some point. It will just not come from the core team soon.

If you are motivated to do so, we'll be happy to give you pointers.

Comment: Does version 3 support multiple checkpoints? I did not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: All version have the **API** to support multiple checkpoint. It is just not in the default implementation. It's like asking "does my computer support multiple keyboard". Yes it does, but it probably only ship with one, but you can buy a second keyboard and plug it in.

Comment: @Matt if I wanted to write a git backend supporting multiple checkpoints, is there a good link to read to get started? I narrowly avoided some catastrophic data loss and I'm feeling motivated at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this, I add multiple checkpoint for every time of saving . https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3563